# Where are recent documents stored in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kde5

In an older version of Kubuntu with KDE 4 it was at ~/.kde/share/apps/RecentDocuments

There's nothing at that location in Kubuntu 15.10 with KDE 5, but recent documents are still tracked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a guess that the new directory might have the same name. I made sure my `mlocate` database was up to date, then searched for it.

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate RecentDocuments
```

I only had a few hits, and it revealed the location in Plasma 5.

```
~/.local/share/RecentDocuments
```

I double checked, and the contents matched the recent documents in `Application Launcher`.

Comment: That location indeed contains the Recent Documents, but the "Recent Documents" submenu of the application menu is also cluttered with a bunch of non-document locations.  Do you know where those "recent locations" that are also shown in the "Recent Documents" menu are stored? Ideally I'd like to clean them with a cronjob - trying to get a proper "Recent Documents" menu that actually has...ya know, only recent documents ;)

Comment: @Metal450 Yeah, more customisation would definitely be useful. I hate the fact that there are applications there now. I'd recommend asking a new question though.

Comment: I'm only getting docs & locations, no applications. I did attempt another question - both on KDE forums 7 weeks ago (https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=166155) and SuperUser 4 weeks ago (https://superuser.com/questions/1555756/kde-recent-documents-only-not-locations). No luck, so I thought I'd ping elswhere people had clearly had experience with this :/